# Nlist equivalent for Linux?

Tags: linux, novell

I am just wondering if there is an Linux equivalent to Novels nlist(). nlist()
does the following:

Privileged processes calling nlist() should beware of the possibility of an unexpected file being substituted as the operand.

The nlist() function returns symbol table information for the specified symbol names, for the executable file whose name is supplied as an argument.

Thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 0):

The function that comes closest that I know about is dlinfo. It is completely undocumented in glibc (no man page, nothing in the info files), but is apparently a clone of a Solaris interface, which is documented:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1465/dlinfo-3c.html#scrolltoc

You can find it declared on Linux in dlfcn.h